# Split string from particular regular expression in c#

Tags: c#

i have one string like

> "8/6/08mz: Last name corrected from Paniaguato Arevalo-Paniaguaas listed on bills/MR, email Shasta, 1132644 06/24/08jh:To
>   Concentra/froi."

and  i want to split this string when i get `"8/6/08mz:"` pattern so my updated string will be following

> "8/6/08mz: Last name corrected from Paniaguato Arevalo-Paniaguaas listed on bills/MR, email Shasta, 1132644" 
>    
> "06/24/08jh:To Concentra/froi."

how can i do it in c# please help me.

Comment: That looks like a rather trivial pattern, something like `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}` and so on. What have you tried?

Comment: advice me what can i do for this in c#

Answer (score 0):

Using `Regex.Split()` and a Regular Expression?

I have a very bad one here:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]{2}:
```

https://regex101.com/r/cEFbbZ/1

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the string starts with what you want, then split on the space preceded by 7 digits:

```
if (s.StartsWith("8/6/08mz: ")) {
    var ans = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[0-9]{7}) ");
}
```